# Is there a way to create a product variant with options using the /products/${productId}/variants endpoint?

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm using BigCommerce with their V3 API to create a store with many products.

Some of the products have hundreds of variations, and the create requests unfortunately timeout sometimes. To combat this, I want to create the base product first, and then individually add the product's variants afterwards.

I've looked through the documentation, and the **Create a Variant Option** seems to almost be the perfect fit.

The issue is it looks like I can't create `option_values` on that request. This means I would have to create all of the option values, then create the variants. I would prefer not to go that route if possible, because a single product could end up taking nearly 1k requests to create everything.

My product schema looks like this:

```
{
    name,
    type,
    weight,
    categories,
    availability,
    price,
    inventory_tracking,
    variants: [
        {
            sku,
            price,
            inventory_level,
            image_url,
            option_values: [
                {
                    option_display_name: 'Color',
                    label: ${color_value}
                },
                {
                    option_display_name: 'Size',
                    label: ${size_value}
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to create a product, and then create variants with new option values at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

When creating variants from the products/{ID}/variants endpoint, the option values do need to be created beforehand. That being said, the way we'd like to approach this is by improving the performance when POSTing a new product + variants so you don't hit timeouts below the 600 variant/product limit. Just wanted to let you know that it's on our radar and something we're working to improve.